# postfix header_checks.pcre wrongly blocking IPHONE emails

Tags: iphone, email, pcre

I have a **postfix/dovecot** mail server which has been working fine for a year or so but today one user came to me with his iPhone and said he couldn't send emails.

It turns out the emails were being rejected by my header_checks.pcre which I set up as per the example in  http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html

The error I got was something like:

> Apr 30 09:48:28 mail06 postfix/cleanup[28849]: 53893A00CD: reject:
>   header Content-Type:
>   image/png;??name=email_logo.png;??x-apple-part-url="part22.05080008.04000601@mydomain.com"
>   from unknown[112.134.156.178]; from=
>   to= proto=ESMTP helo=<[192.168.1.12]>: 5.7.1
>   Attachment name
>   "email_logo.png;??x-apple-part-url="part22.05080008.04000601@mydomain.com"
>   may not end with ".com"

So it seems that the iPhone mail app was appending an "x-apple-part-url" suffix to the attachment name and the PCRE was mistakenly blocking this as a .com instead of allowing through a .png.

Does anyone know how I can safely modify the PCRE in http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html to avoid this happening?

Answer (score 1):

So far as I know ".com" is still a viable extension for Windows malware.  The problem is that the second `.*` in the [example PCRE in the Postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html) is spanning two parameters as if the .com ended the `name` or `filename` parameter.

According to [RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045), `value := token / quoted-string`.  This means you need to cater for both the quoted and unquoted cases by providing appropriate character classes.  You could split into two rules or, to save multiple lists of extensions, do something like:

```
 /etc/postfix/header_checks.pcre:
     /^Content-(Disposition|Type).*name\s*=\s*
       ("(?:[^"]|\\")*|[^();:,\/<>\@\"?=<>\[\]\ ]*)
       ((?:\.|=2E)(
       ade|adp|asp|bas|bat|chm|cmd|com|cpl|crt|dll|exe|
       hlp|ht[at]|
       inf|ins|isp|jse?|lnk|md[betw]|ms[cipt]|nws|
       \{[[:xdigit:]]{8}(?:-[[:xdigit:]]{4}){3}-[[:xdigit:]]{12}\}|
       ops|pcd|pif|prf|reg|sc[frt]|sh[bsm]|swf|
       vb[esx]?|vxd|ws[cfh])(\?=)?"?)\s*(;|$)/x
           REJECT Attachment name $2$3 may not end with ".$4"
```

The new second line of the rule distinguishes between the quoted and unquoted cases and any closing quotation mark is absorbed into $3.

BTW I'd probably stick .mso, .xl, .ocx (obscure MS extensions) and .jar in there too.  Obviously this check is useful against malware floods but doesn't substitute for an up-to-date antivirus or more detailed spam analysis.